# Duplicate symbols between two Google pods

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods, google-play-games

I know `duplicate symbol` is a recurrent issue but this one is particular or a least my knowledge in iOS dev do not help me.

I used to use GooglePlayGames (GPG) in my final application and GoogleCloudMessaging (GCM) in my SDK but today for some reason things started to explode (idea: Due to the last GCM update but I can't get the old version)

Considering the last version of GCM in my SDK, I have:

*Podfile*

```
pod 'MySDK'                 # All good
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging' # Nothing special...
```

*Output*

```
$ pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
...
Installing GGLInstanceID (1.1.5)                 # Dependencies
Installing Google (1.3.2)                        # relative to GCM
Installing GoogleCloudMessaging (1.1.2)            
Installing GoogleIPhoneUtilities (1.1.1)
Installing GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.1.0)
Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.0.0)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.0.3)
Installing GoogleUtilities (1.1.0)
...
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

And in my final application:

*Podfile*

```
pod 'GooglePlayGames' # Nothing special...
```

*Output*

```
$ pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
...
Installing GoogleAppUtilities (1.0.0)           # Dependencies relative
Installing GoogleAuthUtilities (1.0.1)          # to GPG
Installing GooglePlayGames (5.0)
Installing GooglePlusOpenSource (1.7.1)
Installing GoogleSignIn (2.4.0)
...
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

When I build my final application, this is the error I have (explicit but I don't find any solution...)

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GIPLocale in:
/Users/Path/To/App/Pods/GoogleIPhoneUtilities/Libraries/libGIP_Locale.a(GIPLocale.o)
/Users/Path/To/App/Pods/GooglePlayGames/gpg-cpp-sdk/ios/gpg.framework/gpg(GIPLocale.o)
```

As far as I understand, I have `GIPLocale` twice which makes me have duplicate symbol. And if we take a look at the Pods concerned, one belongs to `GPG` and the other to `GCM`.

I tried a lot of things but with no success.
This can easily be reproduce with an empty project and adding both dependency inside the same Podfile. Note that `ENABLE_BITCODE` has to be disabled.

Probably something stupid, somewhere, lost in Xcode configuration...

Comment: This may be useful https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1729

Comment: I've already seen this page before, I tried again but it doesn't really match my case. I posted an issue on GCM Github and it seems there is a real bug. You can check links in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created the [same issue](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/158) on [Google Clound Messaging Github](https://github.com/google/gcm) and the answer is pretty clear, it is a bug they need to fix.

Hopefully it will come soon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the first library (libGIPLocale.a)?  This definitely sounds like an issue where both libraries are making direct use of the same internal library (so the true fix is not on your end), but if the code they're trying to get at is the same, then simply not trying to link in the duplicate could very well fix your linking issues.

Comment: I did but I got an error during GCM initialization when my app starts. ([GIPLocale legalDocsLanguageForPreferences:]: unrecognized selector) Right now I'm waiting for a fix from Google.

Comment: Is there any fix for this? I'm still having this bug with the latest version

Comment: Still having it as well.